# How to prevent the background scrolling when a Portal is rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, react-lifecycle, react-portal

I have component hierarchy that renders in the this manner: Claim->NewModal->Portal. When the portal component is rendered, I don't want the background body to be scrollable at all. Here is my code:
Claim Component:

```
class Claim extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showCalendarModal: false
        }
    }
    openModal = () => {
        this.setState({ showCalendarModal: true });
    };
    closeModal = () => {
        this.setState({ showCalendarModal: false });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragement>
                <a href="javascript: void(0);" onClick={openModal}> Open Modal</a>
                {this.state.showCalendarModal && (<NewModal isModalOpen={showCalendarModal} onClose={this.onModalClose} />)}
            </React.Fragement>
   );
    }
}
```

Here is my NewModal component:

```
import Portal from "./Portal";

class NewModal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isModalOpen: this.props.isModalOpen
        };
    }

  closeModal = () => {
      this.setState({ isModalOpen: false });
      this.props.onClose();
  };
  
  render() {
      const { isModalOpen } = this.state;
      console.log("NewModal is rendered");

      return (
          <Portal show={isModalOpen} onClose={this.closeModal} disableScroll={isModalOpen}>
              <p>A new modal is rendered here</p>
          </Portal>
      );
  }
}
```

Here is my Portal component:

```
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";

class Portal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            mounted: false
        };
        this.portalRef = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.portalRef.current = document.querySelector("#portal");
        this.setState({ mounted: true });
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        const { show, disableScroll } = this.props;
        if (show !== prevProps.show || disableScroll !== prevProps.disableScroll) {
            this.handleScrollLock();
        }
    }

    handleScrollLock() {
        const html = document.querySelector("html");
        const body = document.querySelector("body");
        const { show, disableScroll } = this.props;

        if (disableScroll && show) {
            body.style.overflow = "hidden";
            html.style.overflow = "hidden";
        } else if (disableScroll && !show) {
            body.style.overflow = null;
            html.style.overflow = null;
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        if (this.props.disableScroll) {
            const html = document.querySelector("html");
            const body = document.querySelector("body");
            body.style.overflow = null;
            html.style.overflow = null;
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { children, show, onClose } = this.props;
        const { mounted } = this.state;

        return mounted && this.portalRef.current
            ? createPortal(
                <React.Fragment>{show ? (
                    <React.Fragment>
                      <div onClick={onClose}/>
                    <div>{children}</div></React.Fragment>
                ) : null}</React.Fragment>,
                this.portalRef.current
            )
            : null;
    }
```

When I console log the `prevProps` and `this.props` in `componentDidUpdate`, I get the same values for `disableScroll` and `show`. And hence it does not executes the `handleScrollLock` method. The values for `disableScroll` and show should be true only when the portal is rendered, so the prevProps should have their values are false. (Correct me if I am wrong here.) How can I achieve this?
This worked fine when I used useEffect hook in an another repository. Here is the implementation for it:

```
useEffect(() => {
        portalRef.current = document.querySelector('#portal');
        setMounted(true);
    }, []);

useEffect(() => {
    const html = document.querySelector('html');
    const body = document.querySelector('body');
    if (disableScroll && show) {
        body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
        html.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    }
    else if (disableScroll && !show) {
        body.style.overflow = null;
        html.style.overflow = null;
    }
    return () => {
        if (disableScroll) {
            const html = document.querySelector('html');
            const body = document.querySelector('body');
            body.style.overflow = null;
            html.style.overflow = null;
        }
    };
}, [ show, disableScroll ]);
```

I can't use hooks here as the react version in my repository is an old one and I can't change it. Can anyone point out what I am missing out here?